# How to create dynamic 2 rows of table header using Angular Material?

Tags: angular, typescript, html-table, angular-material, angular-material-table

I want to create a table with dynamic details column like below:

| Level | 6 | 6 | 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **Question** | **Comment** | **Comment** | **Comment** |
| Q1 | 5 - 6 | 7 - 10 |  |
| Q2 | 10 - 20 | 21 - 30 |  |
| Q3 |  |  | 20 - 30 |

The response gives me data like below:

```
[
  {
     'level' : 6,
     'Question' : 'Q1',
     'low' : 5,
     'high' : 6
  },
  {
     'level' : 6,
     'Question' : 'Q1',
     'low' : 7,
     'high' : 10
  },
  {
     'level' : 6,
     'Question' : 'Q2',
     'low' : 10,
     'high' : 20
  },
  {
     'level' : 6,
     'Question' : 'Q2',
     'low' : 21,
     'high' : 30
  },
  {
     'level' : 3,
     'Question' : 'Q3',
     'low' : 20,
     'high' : 30
  }
]
```

How can I achieve the above table for creating dynamic column like 6,3 etc according to response in Angular mat table?

Comment: What are your attempts?

Comment: @imhvost See this is something new and didnot find any reference where I could make 2 rows of header dynamically. I have created a simple table with one row of header and other data but how is dynamic made? Is their any grouping done in Angular Materials?